# PHP Inotify Non-blocking way

Tags: php, linux

I am reading a file in linux which is a log file that keeps on updating weather the file has changed and output it to the webpage. i do it using php inotify but my problem is that it is blocking.

How can i make php inotify non-blocking so i can do other stuff while it is monitoring the text file?.

```
<?php

$fd = inotify_init();


$watch_descriptor = inotify_add_watch($fd, '/tmp/temp.txt', IN_MODIFY);


touch('/tmp/temp.txt');


    $events = inotify_read($fd);

    $contents = file_get_contents('/tmp/temp.txt');
    echo $contents;


inotify_rm_watch($fd, $watch_descriptor);
fclose($fd)

?>
```

Or can i do this in java?..Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. Did you take a look at the Manual? It provides non-blocking event callback examples? If this answer doesn't adequately answer you, please add more information.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.inotify-init.php

```
// Open an inotify instance
$fd = inotify_init();

// - Using stream_set_blocking() on $fd
stream_set_blocking($fd, 0);

// Watch __FILE__ for metadata changes (e.g. mtime)
$watch_descriptor = inotify_add_watch($fd, __FILE__, IN_ATTRIB);

// generate an event
touch(__FILE__);

// this is a loop
while(true){

  $events = inotify_read($fd); // Does no block, and return false if no events are pending  

  // do other stuff here, break when you want...
}

// Stop watching __FILE__ for metadata changes
inotify_rm_watch($fd, $watch_descriptor);

// Close the inotify instance
// This may have closed all watches if this was not already done
fclose($fd);
```

Comment: Well this doesn't work it still loads even when it's in non blocking mode and you can't do anything else while its still waiting for data. I need it to throw out data when changes to the files are made and while doing something else in php..

Comment: Actually this works, but Layke included the blocking read call too. I've corrected the code.

Answer (score 2):

It's like Layke said. You can have it either blocking or non-blocking. If it's non-blocking you have to poll. I think what you want is blocking in a multithreaded way. One thread works in blocking or non-blocking, frequent polling, mode whilst the other thread does something else.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to poll inotify please?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that it will be much easier to this thing by using `node.js.`

You only need the code below: (filename:watch.js)

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var file = '/tmp/temp.txt/';
    fs.watchFile(file, function (curr, prev) {
        console.log('the current mtime is: ' + curr.mtime);
        console.log('the previous mtime was: ' + prev.mtime);
    });
```

then you can run it:

```
    node watch.js
```

It will run persistently.

The `node.js` using javascript to write `server-side` program, it has `non-blocking I/O` model. It can help you do this kind of thing easily.

Here is some related document [`fs.watchFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener)

Comment: Can node.js watch directories too, and does it trigger that function when a files are added into a subdirectory of the directory that's being watched?

Comment: yes, it can watch the file in whole directory. but, not include the subdirectory in node.js raw method. but we can make it by a little code, there are aslo someone  have done this work. node.js is powerful and light. any question please feel free to comment here.

Comment: the function will be triggered when file add into or move from the watched directory.

Comment: @Alex, are you interested in `node.js`?

Answer (score 1):

My preference for something like this would be to use Java as I find it easier to manage background tasks like what you describe.

**Backend**

My approach would be to use Java EE to create a singleton startup thread that implements a scheduler service. The reason for using a singleton startup thread is so your job can run as a background process and is thus non-blocking, freeing up resources for the rest of your application. Also the thread can be accessed using a simply invoking a method on the class. You can schedule the task to read your file every 'n' seconds/minutes etc. for any updates and these can then be made available to your frontend.

Basic Example:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Scheduler {

    private static int count = 0;
    private Weather weather;

    public Weather getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void onStartup() {
        System.out.println("Initialization success.");
    }

   @Schedule(second="*/10", minute="*", hour="*")
   public void execute() {

      byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("weather_updates.txt"));
      String weatherUpdateStr = encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();

      weather = new Weather();
      weather.parse(weatherUpdateStr);

      // Possible addition of logic for push to web socket
   }
}
```

This basic example creates a sigleton thread as your web application container (I would recommend using JBoss 7) starts up. It then creates a scheduled task which executes every 10 seconds. The code provided does a basic Java 7 file read to a string and the `weather.parse()` should contain some logic to convert the string into a Weather object. The weather object is then ready to either be pushed via a web socket or polled via some AJAX request on the frontend.

**Frontend**

There are two possible approaches I would suggest here:

1. Web sockets using HTML5
2. AJAX calls

**1. Web sockets**

Web sockets were introduced into HTML5 as a way of providing dynamic content on a page without the need to refresh or use AJAX calls. [Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) is a great intoduction to websockets in HTML5. [Here is another great example of how to set up HTML5 websockets with Java](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-the-html5-websockets-api/).

**2. AJAX calls**

jQuery provides a great API for AJAX. You can implement a [Timeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) task in jQuery that will intermittently execute some functionality. The functionality you will want to implement is and [AJAX Get request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Basic example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getWeatherUpdate.html",
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached
    },
    success: function(){
        // Update your webpage with weather info
    },
    timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to the React library, it's provide a event-driven, non-blocking I/O Api in PHP, based on the reactor pattern:
http://reactphp.org/